# INSERT queries in Saxon api

Tags: xml, insert, xquery, saxon, xquery-update

Does Saxon xqj api support issuing `insert` queries? 
If No, Is there any academic article discussing this? and what alternative should be used?
If Yes, is there any code example for doing so?

Any answer would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443649/insert-element-into-xml-using-xquery-and-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*XQJ* isn't designed for updating queries, so support for them would always be implementation-dependent.
In [this thread](https://dev.saxonica.com/community/boards/3/topics/1540) from three years ago, Saxon's author Michael Kay wrote that he wouldn't want to do that, so it isn't likely that it's supported now.

If you're OK with using the Saxon-specific [S9API](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/package-summary.html) (which supports updates), you need the non-free *Saxon-EE* version, as the others [don't provide XQuery Update](http://www.saxonica.com/feature-matrix.html) at all.